I keep getting error - Range setFormula: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let usedRange = sheet1.getUsedRange();
    let rowCount: number = usedRange.getRowCount();
    console.log(rowCount);
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("data");
    // Set range L2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("L2").setFormula("=XLOOKUP(I2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A${rowCount},Sheet1!$A$2:$M${rowCount})");
    // Auto fill range
    selectedSheet.getRange("L2").autoFill();
    // Paste to range L1 on selectedSheet from range A1:M1 on sheet1
    selectedSheet.getRange("L1").copyFrom(sheet1.getRange("A1:M1"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Auto fit the columns of range L:L on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("L:L").getFormat().autofitColumns();
}

I want to automate the task of applying XLOOKUP for variable length of records

selectedSheet.getRange("L2").setFormula(\=XLOOKUP(I2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$${rowCount},Sheet1!$A$2:$M$${rowCount})`);`

To use with variable length of records, in most cases, you could lookup the last non-empty row in with reverse lookup option -1: =XLOOKUP(I2, Sheet1!$A$2:XLOOKUP(1, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1), Sheet1!$A$2:XLOOKUP(1, M:M <> "", M:M, , , -1))  (last non-empty row in A and M should be the same.) (no need for VBA)

It looks like there are some syntax issues with how you construct the formula. You'll need to enclose the string with backticks and escape the $ symbols that are used for absolute references, like so:
selectedSheet.getRange("L2").setFormula(`=XLOOKUP(I2,Sheet1!\$A\$2:\$A\$${rowCount},Sheet1!\$A\$2:\$M\$${rowCount})`);

For more information, see this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
Hope that helps!
